# How do you return the Jedis instance back to the pool?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm working on a project that will need to interface with my Redis data store on demand and am using Jedis to do that.

As per the github ["Jedis best practices"](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f) which states:

> Make sure to return the Jedis instance back to the pool when done, otherwise you will leak the connection.

We should return the Jedis instance back to the pool "when done".

I had the idea to create a new pool for every interaction with my data store by initializing a new pool, and closing it at the end of every interaction. But:

> This pool should be configured once and reused.

My next idea was to call `pool.close()` during the exit hook, but rereading the above I'm   not sure if that's what the document is meaning when it says "return the Jedis instance back to the pool". Especially considering that for my current project the application will only restart once a day.

I'm worried about leaking the connection and am looking for some guidance on what this means, and how to work within Jedis best practices. Googling has not been successful, so I'm hoping that someone here can provide some guidance.

Comment: A "pool" presumes that you have a long-lived application that is making repeated trips to Redis. Just close and discard it when your application lifecycle terminates.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The solution was a mix of what you described here as well as closing the resource pool: `pool.getResource()` allocated to the jedis object  via `jedis.close()`Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.